# Update modal dialog in Caliburn Micro from outside the dialog's VM

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have the following situation: I'm trying to load a file into an application (this is a C# based WPF application using Caliburn Micro).

The nature of this file doesn't really matter but the loading process consists of a number of steps that, for large files, can take a while to complete.

What I'm trying to do is have a modal dialog shown in my application that's displayed at the start of the loading process, closed at the end and updated by the application during it so that the text in the dialog reflects where the application has reached in the loading process.

I've got as far as showing a view by passing in the associated view model in a call to windowmanager.ShowDialog() but then nothing happens. I can only assume that this is because the dialog is presumably being displayed synchronously so the subsequent calls that finish the loading as well as update the dialog are never being reached.

In essence this the sort of thing I'm trying at the moment (the VM has a single message string property that's used in the view):

```
windowManager.ShowDialog(ProgressDialogVM);

doSomething();
ProgressDialogVM.Message = "Step 2";
doSomethingElse();
ProgressDialogVM.Message = "Step 3";
doSomethingElseAgain();
ProgressDialogVM.Message = "Step 4";

ProgressDialogVM.TryClose();
```

This is what the property in the dialog VM looks like:

```
private string message = "";
public string Message
{
    get
    {
        return message;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != message)
        {
            message = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(message));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the XAML used for the textbox in case that's relevant here:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Message, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Any thoughts on how to do this would be much appreciated.

*Edit* I've got to the point where I can show the window and get the code to execute. I can even set the property successfully in the view model and show the initial value in the window. The problem now however is that value, whilst it can be set, is not being updated in the corresponding view. It quite happily shows the initial value but no changes past that point.

So in the test sample below the window will show 'Step 0' but does not update to show 'Step 1'.

```
ProgressDialogViewModel ProgressDialogVM = new ProgressDialogViewModel();  
ProgressDialogVM.Message = "Step 0";
windowManager.ShowWindow(ProgressDialogVM, null, null);
ProgressDialogVM.Message = "Step 1";
```

Comment: What is `ProgressDialogVM`? Does it inherit from `MessageBox`?

Comment: It inherits from Screen. MessageBox appears to be a sealed class.

Answer (score 0):

`WindowManager.ShowDialog()` opens a modal window, which is why it blocks the further operations in the main/parent window until the modal window is closed. This is why you are not able to execute the succeeding step in the first code samples while the ProgressDialogVM is opened.

In the second scenario, you have used `WindowManager.ShowWindow` which opens a non-modal Window. This allows further execution of code in the Main/Parent Window. However, it looks like succeeding operations are synchronous and the UI thread isn't hence available to do the UI updation on the ProgressDialogVM.

What you could do is to ensure the intermediate operations like the `doSomethingElse` to be asynchronous.

```
progressDialogVm.Message = "State 01";
_windowManager.ShowWindow(progressDialogVm,null,null);
await DoSomething();
progressDialogVm.Message = "State 02";
await DoSomethingElse();
```

This would ensure your Message Text in the ProgressDialog is updated as desired.